# Dynamic mailing lists

Tags: php, email, mailing-list, mail-server

I have a website that manages schedules and rosters for a sports league. I'm about to add a feature that will dynamically create mailing lists for teams within the league. So a team captain would be able to email team-14@site.com and that email would go out to all the players on the team. I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel on this, so I'm looking for anything that already exists that could do at least part of the work for me.

**1. Is there a webapp that does this?**

I'm looking for an app with an API that lets me create/update/delete mailing lists dynamically and send mail to those lists. It should also let me specify who is/is not allowed to send emails to each list (for example, I may only want the captains of a team to be able to email the team)

**2. If not, what are some programs/tools that I could use to do part of the process for me?**

My site runs on LAMP using the Symfony framework. Is there a good mail server and/or mailing list manager that would be easy for my site to work with?

**3. Any guidance on rolling my own?**

Assuming I don't find an easy pre-existing solution, I will probably have to write much of this myself. Do you know of any articles/posts/projects that are trying to do something similar? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2. Kind of this? http://atmail.com/kb/?p=222

I recommend Exim as MTA/SMTP and Dovecot as POP/IMAP server (if you'd never set up the mail server on Linux, you'll find that it is a *set* of different applications, usually separately configured)

1. google: php  mailing lists

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/mailing-list-managers/

http://www.thefreecountry.com/php/mailing-list-scripts.shtml

etc.